# SharePoint 2010 Foundation and Taxonomy

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, managed-metadata, taxonomy

I need to apply Taxonomy in my company SharePoint 2010 Foundation environment. But since 
Taxonomy or Manage Metadata Service is not available in SharePoint Foundation. What option do I have.

Thanks.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm in a similar situation. I only have 2010 Foundation, and want to do taxonomy the right way. Did Ashish's suggestion work well for you? If so, would you be willing to answer some questions about what you did? Here's where I am in the process... http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/58279/i-need-advice-on-a-keyword-strategy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot completely match the broad feature set of Managed Metadata but you can accomplish a subset of it using the techniques that existed before Managed Metadata was introduced:

Define Taxonomic Metadata – Create custom site lists to be used for the management of metadata attributes you want to surface as controlled vocabularies for your site users.

Define Site Columns – Create new site columns that get their information from the custom lists created above via lookup fields.

Define Content Types – Create new site content types and add the appropriate site columns as required.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciate it. Does this approach work across site collections or only for within one site collection

Comment: Shared Content Types are available only with SharePoint Server Products - again part of Managed Metadata Services. See http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx for product comparison.