# I need advice on a keyword strategy

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, metadata

I think my question is general enough to not be version-specific, but if not, we're running Foundation 2010 with minimal development (SPD, Vis Studio, etc.) capability.

I have a 3500-document repository that recently got converted to a SharePoint library. Our metadata is almost non-existent and we're relying on full text document searches to find content. Since keywords were not part of the initial repository, they were created from scratch in a spreadsheet a few years ago. Col 1 is the document name, Col 2 is a column delimited list of keywords. This is the data I'm trying to populate into SharePoint's metadata columns.

Here's where I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around things.

Let's say that an Excel record is this: `document_foo.doc; keyword_foo1,keyword_foo2,...,keyword_foo8`. I plan to cut-and-paste the records from Excel to a Datasheet view of my library.

My question is this: if I paste a list (`keyword_foo1,keyword_foo2,...,keyword_foo8`) into an empty metadata column does that whole string of 8 keywords become the sort value? or would Sharepoint recognize `keyword_foo1` as a seaparate and distinct keyword from `keyword_foo2`? That's out intention, but I suspect it won't.

But if I create ten distinct keyword columns, and reformat the single Excel keyword field into up to ten separate keywords in ten separate columns, I end up potentially missing something if I search in `keyword_foo2` and the value lives in `keyword_foo4`. With that, I run into the potential of having a list of thousands of keywords from which users get to choose when creating a new document--that seems needlessly unweildy to me.

In a perfect world, I'd like to see multiple choice check boxes created from the keyword list; but then I'd have to add a carriage return instead of the spaces in the filename, right? And I'd have to figure out a way to prevent a list of a few thousand keywords from accumulating over time.

I'm a little too close to the project too see it clearly. Does anyone have any suggestions or strategies for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use an enterprise key words column, and separate the existing keywords with a semicolon instead of a commar it would nicely separate them. However this would still be more editing than it sounds like you want to do...

Comment: Ah, but I can do a global replace in the Excel keyword column to replace "," with ";". 2 clicks, 2 keystrokes, another click. e viola--a properly formatted column to cut-n-paste.  Is there a specific column type into which you'd recommend loading this data?

Comment: Follow instructions here:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/add-an-enterprise-keywords-column-to-a-list-or-library-HA102832526.aspx

Using enterprise keywords rather than just adding a text metadata field means you can easily refine your searches later using the bar down the left hand side of the search results.

Comment: AWESOME! I've been looking for this for a while. Just hoping that our admins have it enabled in our installation. But that's my issue....

Comment: Cool :) Good luck.

Comment: ...aaaand buzzkill. Enterprise keywords not available in Foundation. :|  Back to the ol' drawing board.

Comment: Ahh that sucks. Does it have managed metadata at all?

Comment: No Managed Metadata either...but now I'm exploring http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27706/sharepoint-2010-foundation-and-taxonomy 'cause it seems like my only option at this point.

Comment: Im interested to hear how you get on...

Comment: Me too. Hopefully it'll be a lot more than a confirmation of my theory that Foundation is sophisticated crippleware. :)

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: ...stymied by the powers that be. I know what to do, they just like the procetag of Foundation a lot better than robust search & metadata, I guess. :(